# Updating widgets in kivy (python)

Tags: python, widget, kivy

Can anyone explain to me how you update widgets in kivy? I have a code sample here:

```
class Game(Widget):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(*sky_color)
        Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=self.size)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(*grass_color)
        Rectangle(pos=(0,0), size=(800,75))
    with self.canvas:
        Label(text='Funky Chicken', font_size='50sp', pos=(360, 400))
    with self.canvas:
        Button(text='Play', font_size='20')

class FunkyChickenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Game(size=Window.size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FunkyChickenApp().run()
```

This is supposed to be a game menu so some labels and stuff have to change when you press some buttons.

Edit*
What i mean is how do I use Kivy clock

Comment: so you want to use the Clock, do you want to do a periodic task?

Comment: no if i press the button i want a change to be visible. It seems like kivy only render the window one time at the start.

Comment: What changed do you want visible? please understand that we are not in your head, we do not know what you want unless you put it explicitly. Also provide a [mcve], and focus on a specific problem, for example say when you press the button I want that to happen. Your question is not clear. Also read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind actions to the buttons (the documentation has a few examples https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html).

i.e.

```
button = Button(text='Play', font_size='20')
button.bind(on_press = do_something_you_want)
```

Comment: yes, of course, but to make any action visible you need some kind of fps or am i wrong?

Comment: @Heimdonger fps? Do you mean frame per second?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes i have heard something about kivy clock